# Django: Long field (BigIntegerField) For MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, long-integer, django-nonrel

I want to assign a model field to store a Long integer type in MongoDB. I've tried it with BigIntegerField but it is still kept as Integer field in MongoDB. I've tried using:

```
models.BigIntegerField()
```

Which model field should I use?
Note: I've used django-nonrel for DJango-MongoDB relation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saving a large enough value?  It may also matter what version of python you are using.  From the API docs:

> A Python int will be saved as a BSON int32 or BSON int64 depending on
>   its size. A BSON int32 will always decode to a Python int. In Python
>   2.x a BSON int64 will always decode to a Python long. In Python 3.x a BSON int64 will decode to a Python int since there is no longer a long type.

Also, a python long should always map to a BSON 64-bit integer:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.3rc1/api/bson/son.html

Comment: When I look at the value in MongoDB, I see that the field is created as Integer. Probably Mongo will not accept the value exceeds Integer. Actually my problem is keeping the field as Integer in MongoDB. Django MongoDB fork convert BigInteger form field to Integer field in Mongo.